# What are typical "crest factor" values for significantly non-linear typical household loads?

Tags: power, switch-mode-power-supply, inverter, led-driver

What are typical "[crest factor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crest_factor)" values for significantly non-linear typical household loads?

By *household loads*, I mean anything either plugged in to a receptacle or hard-wired like ceiling lights.
By *significantly non-linear*, I loosely mean that the current waveform significantly deviates from a sine, like for lamp ballasts and switching power supplies. Excluded are (probably) purely resistive loads and inductive / capacitative loads with "clean enough" sine waveforms. Google search did not reveal much. Only a value of roughly 3 (with a lot of variation) for LEDs and personal computers. I would love to see more numbers backed by measurements or guidelines.

Comment: People usually deal with *power factor* abbreviated PF. PF is linked to phase displacement and current distortion. PF is 1 for a resistance supplied from a sinusoidal source and less than unity for other configurations. It is specified as \$cos(\phi)\$ for sinusoidal excitation and inductive/capacitive loads such as former light ballasts or motors for instance. A load supplied by a full-wave rectifier exhibits a poor PF, usually 0.5-0.6 and there are plenty of household appliances having this characteristic.